# Segmentation fault in inititalizing a binary search tree after second insertion using a iterative insert function

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, initialization, binary-search-tree

I'm getting a segmentation fault after trying to insert a second node into the tree, a segmentation fault is thrown. Is the segmentation fault due to the `initialize` function or `insert`? And how do I solve it by making changes in server.c?

client.c file:

```
int main()
{
    Tree my_tree;
    initialize(&my_tree);
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d", &element);
            insert(&my_tree, element);
            break;
        case 2:
               exit(0);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

server.c file

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} Node;

typedef struct tree
{
    Node *root;
} Tree;

void initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    tree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    tree->root = NULL;
}

void insert(Tree *tree, int data)
{
    Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    if(tree->root == NULL) 
        tree->root = temp;    
    else
    {
        Node *prev,*curr;
        prev = NULL;
        curr = tree->root;
        while(curr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->data < curr->data){
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->left;
            }
            if(temp->data >curr->data){
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->right;
            }
        }
        if(temp->data < prev->data)
            prev->left = temp;
        if(temp->data > prev->data)
            prev->right = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `initialize` function won't work very well. Have you skipped a chapter in your text-book about pointers and passing objects and what is meant by e.g. the address-of operator `&`?

Answer (score 0):

```
void initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    tree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    tree->root = NULL;
}
```

Change to

```
void initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    if (tree) {
     tree->root = NULL;
    }
}
```

When you allocate memory to `tree` you are making it to point new memory location, thus your original `tree`'s root node will not be initialized to `NULL` and also you introduce memory leaks.

Comment: Why should it be like that? Please try to add an explanation, otherwise the OP might never understand the reason.

Comment: Oh okay..I tried this. However, the same problem continues. I gave inputs as 1 3 and 1 2 after which it threw a segmentation fault

Comment: one possibility is, if you enter same value again `(ex: 1 2 1)` then your `void insert(Tree *tree, int data)` functions goes for toss, since it iterates continuously and crashes at some point. can be avoided by adding `if ( temp->data == curr->data ) break;` inside `while`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing the `Tree` object you actually use in your program (`tree` in main), you allocate a new `Tree` object and initialize that object. Effectively, `initialize` doesn't do anything but leak memory.

To fix this, replace

```c
void initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    tree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    tree->root = NULL;
}
```

with

```c
void initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    tree->root = NULL;
}
```

---

The OP points out there's a second error. This where I point out that one shouldn't be depending on the kindness of strangers, and learn how to debug such problems.

You could use a debugger.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g a.c -o a && gdb --args ./a
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/ikegami/a
1
3
1
2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555547b1 in insert (tree=0x7fffffffdda0, data=2) at a.c:39
39                  if(temp->data >curr->data){
(gdb) print temp
$1 = (Node *) 0x555555756690
(gdb) print curr
$2 = (Node *) 0x0
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 1433] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Another approach would be to use `-fsanitize=address` when compiling the program.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -fsanitize=address a.c -o a && ./a
1
3
1
2
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==1370==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x556253e76e87 bp 0x7ffe3a28e390 sp 0x7ffe3a28e360 T0)
==1370==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1370==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x556253e76e86 in insert /home/ikegami/tmp/a.c:39
    #1 0x556253e771af in main /home/ikegami/tmp/a.c:64
    #2 0x7fc3bdadcb96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x556253e76b29 in _start (/tmp/ikegami/a+0xb29)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/ikegami/tmp/a.c:39 in insert
==1370==ABORTING
```

But approach show that `temp->data >curr->data` is the culprit. Using the debugger, we saw that `curr` is `NULL`, so `curr->data` is at issue. Now you know that you need figure out if why `curr` is NULL when you don't expect it to be.

Comment: I made that change but there's seems to be no change in the error. The inputs I give are 1 3, then 1 2..after which there's a seg fault thrown

Comment: It is possible there is more than one error. You should run your program under a debugger and find where the error occurs. (On linux, you could use `gdb` and use `bt` to get a back trace when it halts.) Alternatively, using `-fsanitize=address` when you compile the program should also pinpoint the error when you run the program.

Comment: I've added to my answer.